# Patterns to write to DynamoDB from SQS queue with maximum throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I would like to set up a system that transfers data from an SQS queue to DynamoDB. Is there a mechanism to write at the approximate maximum throughput of the respective DynamoDB table if this is the only place that writes into that table avoiding throttling errors as much as possible?

I haven't seen such a pattern yet. If I have a lambda behind the SQS queue it is hard to measure how many writes are currently occuring because I have no control over the number of lambda instances. Then there might be temporary throughput limitations that need to be handled. The approach I have been thinking about is to have some sort of adaptive mechanism that lowers the write speed if throttling errors occur, possibly supported by real-time queries to CloudWatch to get the throughput in the last few seconds.

I have read the posts related to this topic here but didn't find a solution to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: DynamoDB has on-demand mode. Have you considered it?

Comment: Yes. I am already using it but I am talking about the hard limit of 40,000 write request units per table during load peaks that I want to avoid to hit.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a lambda behind the SQS queue it is hard to measure how many writes are currently occuring because I have no control over the number of lambda instances

Yes you do !

To me, lambda is definitely the way to go. You can set a maximum concurrency limit on every lambda function so that it does not fire too many parallel invocations. [More details here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/set-concurrency-limits-on-individual-aws-lambda-functions/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20a%20numerical,a%20given%20account%20is%201%2C000.)

Also, unless you are doing some fine-tuned costs optimization, `dynamoDB` provides a [on-demand](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-on-demand-no-capacity-planning-and-pay-per-request-pricing/) feature where you don't have to care about provisioning (and therefore throttling) anymore. Using this feature could also guarantee that no throttling occurs.